# Assigning a pointer field to a casted value

Tags: pointers, go

I'm sure this is just a syntax thing I'm not aware of but this is the struct with pointer fields:

```
type someStruct struct {
    StringVal string     `json:"val_str"`
    IntVal    *int64     `json:"val_int"`
}
```

I'm trying to return an instance of this struct like so, where `aValue` is an `int64` value and I'm trying to get the `IntVal` pointer to point to it:

```
return someStruct{IntVal: &(int64(aValue))}
```

I get this error:

```
cannot take the address of int64(d)
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to first assign the int64 to a variable:

```
aValueTmp := int64(aValue)
return someStruct{IntVal: &aValueTmp}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way - instantuiate a variable and give a pointer to it. Or in one line:

```
return someStruct{
    IntVal: func(i int64) *int64 {return &i}(aValue)
}
```